# Get the corresponding value of 80 % of my data

Tags: r

I want to calculate which value correspond to 80% of a column data in order to use this value as a limit value (Xlimit). After that I want to get column data>Xlimit.

Comment: This question seems unfinished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
x = data.frame(a=sample(1:10),b=sample(1:10))
aLim = quantile(x$a,0.8)
xUpdated = x[x$a>=aLim,]
```